# Unreachable code and not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

Ok I'm getting an unreachable code and not all code paths return value from this block of code

```
private string MoveForward()
{
    //if current direction is east, GetRoomEast
    if (Player.CurrentDirection == "EAST")
    {
        return GetroomEast();

        if (Player.NextMove != "")

        {
            Player.Y++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Bumped into a Wall");
        }
        //if GetRoomEast is not "", then playercol = playercol+1;
        //if current direction is west...
    }
}
```

and my initialized variables at the top are

```
public struct DragonPlayer
{
    public int X, Y;
    public string CurrentDirection;
    public string NextMove;
}

public class DragonGameboard
{
    public string[,] GameboardArray;
    public DragonPlayer Player;
    private Random r;

    public DragonGameboard()
    {
        GameboardArray = new string[4, 4];
        Player.CurrentDirection = "EAST";
        Player.NextMove = "";
        r = new Random();
        Player.X = r.Next(0, 4);
        Player.Y = r.Next(0, 4);
        GenerateRandomBoard();
    }
}
```

Why is it doing this? I'm sure it has to be something really silly but I'm having trouble figuring out what it is?

Comment: I meant I'm getting those errors at the top.

Comment: Did you try researching the errors? It pretty much sums it up: you don't return a value from all code paths, while you have a return type of `string`, while "unreachable code" means that that code will never be reached, because you return before it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Beucase using Google is harder than asking on Stack Overflow `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from your function before your if statement,it's never going to your if statement.Therefore your if statement become **unreachable code**

```
 return GetroomEast();

        if (Player.NextMove != "")
```

You should put this return statement after the if statement.

Comment: This would not fix the "not all code paths return a value" error

Answer (score 0):

Every path of your code has to return value of type `string`. Plus you have code that can never execute, namely:

```
if (Player.NextMove != "")
{
    Player.Y++;
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You Bumped into a Wall");
}
```

You've already returned a value, so nothing after that gets executed.

Furthermore, every path that results in ending of the function HAS TO return a value. Go through your code logically and find the scenarios, you'll find plenty.

Maybe I'd suggest to start slow and learn the basics, because these mistakes are really fundamental to any programming language + you already got the message, that is pretty clear. Programming games isn't really a good starting point for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your `MoveForward()` forward method to return a string, but you're not returning one. Change the definition to:

```
private void MoveForward();
```

...or return a string.

Comment: But he has return GetroomEast(); I would say he is trying to return something.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments in the code to show you why have unreachable code and why all code paths do not return a value.

```
private string MoveForward()
{
    if (Player.CurrentDirection == "EAST")
    {
        return GetroomEast(); //Once you return the value here it ends the call.

        if (Player.NextMove != "") //This line (or anything below it) will never run.
        {
            Player.Y++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Bumped into a Wall");
        }
        //if GetRoomEast is not "", then playercol = playercol+1;
        //if current direction is west...
    }

    //We reach here if Player.CurrentDirection does not equal "EAST"
    //As there is no more code there is no returned value.
    //You would need to do something like return NoValidMove()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line, `return GetroomEast()` the execution is bailed out of the loop and hence, u are getting unreachable code error. Also nothing is returned inside the next if , else blocks. As your method is of string return type....it has to return string..